# How can I tell Which bazel aspect outputs are still relevant

Tags: bazel, bazel-aspect

As part of our efforts to create a bazel-maven transition interop tool (that creates maven sized jars from more granular sized bazel jars),
we have written an `aspect` that runs on `bazel build` of the entire bazel repo and writes important information to `txt` files `outputs` (e.g.: *jar file paths*, *compile deps targets* and *runtime deps targets*, etc.)

We ran across an issue where the repo's code was changed such that some of the `txt` file were not written anymore. But the old `txt` file from previous runs (before the code change) remained!

Is there a way to know that these txt files are no longer relevant?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to run with --build_event_json_file=file.json and try to locate generated artifacts. For example we use it on ci.bazel.io to locate actual test.xml file that were generated: https://github.com/bazelbuild/continuous-integration/blob/09975cbb487a84a62ca1e43aa43e7c6fe078f058/jenkins/lib/src/build/bazel/ci/BazelUtils.groovy#L218

The definition of the protocol can be found in [build_event_stream.proto](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/buildeventstream/proto/build_event_stream.proto)